# Getting table of coordinates from polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, coordinates, export, gps

I would like to gather all of the GPS coordinates within a set area as a table to transfer it to Excel or sheets.

I designed a rough shape of the area with the polygon tool in the layer and now im stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [select by location](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#qgisselectbylocation) tool to select all points that fall inside the polygon. Set the points as input, select `are within` and the polygon as `By comparing to the features from` (see screenshot). You can than right click on the point layer / export / Save Selected Features As… and choose MS Office Open XML Table as output format to save only the selected points.

[image]